# sending email from wordpress not working in server

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using wordpress function to send email wp_mail. But its not working when there is a Content type header.
i tried both

```
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
```

and

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type','set_contenttype');
        function set_contenttype($content_type){
            return 'text/html';
        }
```

and its not sending any emails. But if i remove content-type from here its working properly.
What could be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this another way to set the *Mail Content Type* to *HTML*:

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
```

then call `wp_mail` function:

```
wp_mail('whoever@whatever.com', 'Subject', 'Message');
```

*i hope it works for you, thanks !*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Wordpress website...
I have ran this command to activate the plugin which enables the plugin,
So now I receive email from my Wordpress website.

`wp plugin activate mailgun`

Check if the plugin is indeed activated with the following command.

`wp plugin list --status=active`